# const char* a[4]; can I change a[] values?

Tags: c++, constants

I thought const char* a[4] means the elements of a[] are const and so I cannot change it after initialization. however, the following code shows me that they can be changed. I am confused... What is const here for?

```
#incldue<iostream>  
#include<string>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
            int order=1;
            for(int i=1; i<10;++i,++order){
                    const char* a[2];
                    int b = 10;
    //              a[0] = to_string(order).c_str();
                    a[0] = "hello world";
                    a[1] = to_string(b).c_str();
                    cout << a[0] << endl;
                    cout << a[1] << endl;
                    cout << "**************" << endl;
                    a[0] = "hello" ;
                    cout << a[0] << endl;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const` qualifier is applied in quite intuitive way. So we have:

**1)** Mutable array of two pointers pointing to mutable content: `char* a[2]`:

```
a[0] = nullptr; //Ok
a[0][0] = 'C'; //Ok
```

**2)** Mutable array of two pointers pointing to immutable content: `const char* a[2]`:

```
a[0] = nullptr; //Ok
a[0][0] = 'C'; //Error
```

**3)** Immutable array of two pointers pointing to mutable content: `char* const a[2]`:

```
a[0] = nullptr; //Error
a[0][0] = 'C'; //Ok
```

**4)** Immutable array of two pointers pointing to immutable content: `const char* const a[2]`:

```
a[0] = nullptr; //Error
a[0][0] = 'C'; //Error
```

Note, that in case **3** and **4**, `a` needs initializer (as const variable cannot be changed). Example:

```
const char* const a[2] =
{
    ptr1,
    ptr2
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring an array of 2 pointer to const char.  You are able to change the pointers (make them point to something differen), but you can't change the memory they point to.  So you can do

```
a[0] = "hello world";
```

but you cannot capitalize the "hello" by later doing

```
a[0][0] = 'H';
```

Answer (score 1):

`const char *a[4]  with the combination priority.
       ^^^^^^^^^^1
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^2`

That's mean you got 4 char pointer room and each of them can point to a char array.  The "const" qualifier specifies that you only can read but not modify.

ex:

`char str1[] = "hello"`

`char str2[] = "good"`

`const char *ptr = str1;`

`cout << ptr << endl; // is correct for read`

`*(ptr + 1) = "a"; // it will alert an error by the compiler, you can't modify`

`ptr = st2;  // is correct, point to another char array(or string)`

`cout << ptr << endl;`